# prevent xelatex from compressing the output

Tags: xetex

In a huge book I edit, I sometimes simplify (beautify, or change in some other way) the global macros defined in the preamble via `\def` or `\(new|renew|provide)command` and then observe whether the change had any effect on the compilation time and on the output PDF file.  For this purpose, I measure the times for compiling the book via `\usr\bin\time -p <my compilation command>` and compare the file before the changes with the file after the changes with `diff -a book_before_the_changes.pdf book_after_the_changes.pdf`.  When the macro simplification had no effect, the only change `diff` spits out is a human-readable ACSII timestamp, which I can read off the screen. When the macro simplification did have some effect, `diff` spits out a bunch of unreadable gibberish, which leads me to examine the situation further by a command such as `diffpdf`, which takes way, way longer.

Recently, I switched from `pdflatex` to `xelatex`, which compresses the output PDF files in such a way that `diff -a book_before_the_changes.pdf book_after_the_changes.pdf` ALWAYS outputs unreadable gibberish. Is there a way to handle this problem, e.g., by preventing the compression, or by *quickly* comparing the previous and the current version for meaningful changes via some other utility? If there is such a way, what would it be?

Comment: Ulrike has given a suggestion of z0 whilst you may use a slightly higher number and general advise is use z9 for final however I would look at z7 and z8 decompess times to ensure an end user is not put off by the viewer decompression times see  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263695/170109

Comment: I understood need/desire for zero but some diff(ers) can do some levels of decompress prior to shifting for visual  comparison, thus "may" depending on your tool-set, main suggestion was consider joe public when publishing

Comment: agreed no decompress options in diffutils

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid the compression with a \special:

```
\documentclass{article}

\special{dvipdfmx:config z 0}
\begin{document}
blbl

\end{document}
```

The `l3build` testing system can also make test based on the pdf-output -- it creates file where binaries and other stuff that changes during compilation (like dates) are removed.

Comment: Well I do my testing with l3build, but it is mostly luatex related, I can't say how well it works with xelatex, and I can't say it if is useful for your usecase.

Comment: Also `xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -z 0"` can be used. I'm not sure it's possible to act also on object streams.

Comment: @egreg object streams can be set with `\special{dvipdfmx:config C 0x40}` (see regression-test).

Comment: Regarding the font name set the environment variables as describe here (with my comment) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391541/2388