# Control PDF ID with ConTeXt (reproducible builds)

Tags: pdf, context

I'm trying to control the ID field in PDFs produced by ConTeXt.

When I run ConTeXt twice on the same input file, the resulting PDF files have different IDs, which can be checked e.g. by running `grep -a "R/ID"`.

For pdf/xe/lua-LaTeX, this ID depends on the current time and the pathname of the PDF. The "current time" can be fixed using the environment variable [`SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239059/how-to-create-identical-pdf-files-with-xelatex/391541#391541).

Since ConTeXt uses luatex as its engine (or optionally pdftex / xetex), I would have expected that the same method applies here, but it doesn't work.

How do I force ConTeXt to produce PDFs with identical ID if given identical input?

Comment: I deleted my answer because it failed by
`fatal error: kpse library is accessed (key: set_program_name)`
as Henri said. Was my previous test illusion?

Comment: I would have expected that `context --nodates file` works, but I still get a date in the pdf so I would suggest to ask on the context mailing list.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! I don't really care about the date fields in the PDF, only the ID. Background: a PDF viewer I use stores settings incl. scroll position based on the ID.

Comment: But `--nodates` doesn't control the PDF ID either.

Comment: @A. Donda: If you need only fixed ID, see
`\pdfvariable trailerid`
near line 722 in
`doc/luatex/base/luatex-modifications.tex`