# Produce the same binary PDF file after several compilations

Tags: pdf, git

I know this question has been asked before, but I can't find an old reference on this subject, so feel free to point to my duplicate post if you have a link to an older post.

Working with LaTeX, PDF and git is a real headache because at each compilation, the binary PDF file changes but not the visual PDF if no changes are made inside the associated LaTeX file.

How do you produce the same PDF after compiling the same LaTeX file several times? Is this type of solution bad? (I have a worse solution for hiding the PDF in git, but I'd like to omit it).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239059/how-to-create-identical-pdf-files-with-xelatex/391541#391541