# How do I configure pdflatex to output binary-equivalent PDFs if the input tex file is unchanged?

Tags: pdftex, pdf

I build a PDF document from a LaTeX source file as part of [static Dwebsite generation](https://docs.ipfs.io/how-to/websites-on-ipfs/static-site-generators/#hugo), but every run of pdflatex outputs a file that hashes to a different [IFPS Content ID](https://docs.ipfs.io/concepts/content-addressing/). This triggers spurious regeneration of the root CID. Can `pdflatex` generate a PDF that is binary-equivalent to previous runs (assuming an unchanged input file) so the PDF output hashes to the same CID?

[The pdflatex manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/pdftex.1.html) doesn't list any options that appear relevant. Per [http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/pdfdoc/pdfdoc/pdfdoc.html](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/%7Enlct/latex/pdfdoc/pdfdoc/pdfdoc.html), I have added something like this to the top of the LaTeX file:

```
\pdfinfo{
   /Producer (pdfTeX)
   /Author ()
   /Title  ()
   /CreationDate (D:20040502195600)
   /ModDate (D:20040502195600)
   /PTEX.Fullbanner (Generated with pdfTeX)
}
```

Comparing the files in hexdiff shows deltas in an /ID property that looks like a GUID. This property doesn't appear to be modifiable by the \pdfinfo block. Is there any way to hardcode or disable the generation of this property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set reproducible behaviour by setting the environment variables `SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH` and `FORCE_SOURCE_DATE` see `texdoc pdftex` section 4.

`SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH` should be the number of seconds since 1970 that you want to fix the date for, and `FORCE_SOURCE_DATE` should be 1

You can also control these fields from within the tex document eg `\pdftrailerid` controls the id at the end and  `\pdfsuppressptexinfo=-1` would suppress the printing of the info information.

Comment: I wasn't able to get \pdfsuppressptexinfo=-1 working, but a combination of `\pdftrailerid{}` and the `\pdfinfo` block I mentioned in my question seems to have done the trick. Thanks!

Comment: When validating my solution, I got tripped up thinking `\pdfsuppressptexinfo=-1` was working, but it turned out to be a clock resolution issue. I was generating both PDFs with a chain of shell commands, and the mod/creation date format didn't have sufficient resolution to measure the delta. The solution: insert a sleep between invocations of pdflatex to make sure the difference in mod times is observable.